# Performance overhead when inserting data in two tables using EF 6

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 to perform CRUD operations. I need to insert data in two tables  and it is working as expected but below function itself is taking 3 seconds .  I don't know why but i need to figure out and reduce this time.

```
 public int SaveRequestDetails(RequestEntity requestEntity)
    {

        try
        {
            if (requestEntity != null)
            {
                Request request = new Request();
                request.SourceMessageXML = requestEntity.SourceMessageXml;
                request.RequestMessageXml = requestEntity.RequestMessageXml;
                request.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;


                RequestDetails requestDetail = new RequestDetails();
                requestDetail.ClientFlag = false;
                requestDetail.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                requestDetail.RequestDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                requestDetail.EmailFlag = false;


                request.RequestDetails.Add(requestDetail);

                _unitOfWork.RequestRepository.Insert(request);
                _unitOfWork.Save();  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you logged the SQL queries generated by EF? Or used SQL profiler to see the traffic to the server?

Comment: What's the size of the XML fields?